# Calling a function in an mxml file from outside

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

I have a basic mxml app which looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="800" height="600">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[


        public function init():void{

        }
```

this swf is loaded into another swf using Loader and added with addChild(loader);

i then need to call the init function from the parent swf. how can i do this?
just calling

```
loader.content.init();
```

fails.

another question is, what is the exact classname of this mxml file?

thanks!

Comment: You say, that calling method fails. How can we know, why it fails? Provide us error text and code used for loading swf.

Comment: the exact error is: ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property init()
 not found on _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager and there is no default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using an interface instead of directly referring to the class of the application mxml.

1. Define an interface:

   ```
   package behaviors {
       interface Initialiazable 
       {
           function init():void;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement the interface in the application mxml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <mx:Application implements="behaviors.Initialiazable"
       width="800" height="600"
       xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
       <mx:Script>
           <![CDATA[
           public function init():void{
               trace("Application.init()");
           }
   ```
3. Loading the SWF inside other app should be something like this:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
       <mx:Script>
       <![CDATA[

       import mx.events.FlexEvent;
       import mx.managers.SystemManager;

       import behaviors.Initializable;

       private var loadedApp:Initializable;

       protected function handleSWFLoaderComplete(e:Event):void
       {
           // wait for the Flex application to load
           var loadedAppSystemManager:SystemManager = e.target.content as SystemManager;
           loadedAppSystemManager.addEventListener(FlexEvent.APPLICATION_COMPLETE, handleApplicationComplete);
       }

       protected function handleApplicationComplete(e:FlexEvent):void
       {
           // cast the loaded application to the Interface
           loadedApp = (Initializable) e.currentTarget.application;
           loadedApp.init();
       }
       ]]>
       </mx:Script>

       <mx:SWFLoader source="LoadedApp.swf" complete="handleSWFLoaderComplete(event)"/>

   </mx:Application>
   ```

Comment: thanks but unfortunately this fails with the error: TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert _Main_mx_managers_SystemManager@113720a1 to com.IInit.